# Different jboss version on same machine

Tags: jboss

Now we are using jboss 6.1.1 final version on our production server. Now we want to deploy our new project on jboss AS 7.

So is it possible to run different version of jboss on same machine? Please provide some guidance regarding same.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can deploy new project on different server.

Only thing you have to take care is Port numbers. Because by default both server uses same port numbers like `8080 for http` and `8443 for https`. If project is already running on Jboss6 and now you are configuring Jboss7 then change `standalone.xml` in `<JBOSS_HOME>\standalone\configuration`.

Find `<socket-binding-group` tag, it should be at bottom of file.

Change port numbers like, `8090 for http` and `8442 for https`.